# How to copy a particular extension file from a directory and sub-directory to other directory using batch script or linux cmmand

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file, scripting

lets say i have a dir C:\Project\File\ this directory contains folder1,folder2,folder3 and so on. 
folder1, folder2 and folder3 have files with extension .txt
now i want to copy all the .txt file from all the folder to a folder test in path C:\Users\Use\Desktop\Test

How to do this using batch scripting or using linux command.

Answer (score 1):

as batchfile: for (recursive `/r`) all .txt files copy the file to `<new path>\<name>.<extension>` (`%%~nxa`):

```
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do @ECHO copy "%%a" "%C:\Users\Use\Desktop\Test\%%~nxa"
```

if you want to try on command line, use a single `%` instead of double `%%`.

Remove `@ECHO`, if the output is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

use `find` with exec:

```
find C:\\Project\\File -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} C:\\Users\\Use\\Desktop\\Test \;
```

I'm not sure about the directories because you mention windows style but want find (unix style).

Comment: Is this meant for cygwin?

Comment: Question was for linux, but the paths were provided like if it was for windows, so I don't know :)

Comment: I am using cygwin in windows 10 system.

Comment: Use `cygpath` to convert between Windows and Cygwin (Unix) file path formats